# Normalize adjency matrix (in pandas) with MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjency matrix (dm) of items vs items; the value between two items (e.g., item0,item1) refers to the number of times these items appear together. How can I scale all the values in pandas between 0 to 1?

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
```

However, I am not sure how to apply scaler to the pandas data frame.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the resulting array back to the dataframe with loc:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (5, 5)))

df
Out[277]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  2  3  2  3  1
1  2  3  4  4  2
2  2  3  4  3  2
3  1  1  2  1  4
4  4  2  2  3  1

df.loc[:,:] = scaler.fit_transform(df)

df
Out[279]: 
          0    1    2         3         4
0  0.333333  1.0  0.0  0.666667  0.000000
1  0.333333  1.0  1.0  1.000000  0.333333
2  0.333333  1.0  1.0  0.666667  0.333333
3  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  1.000000
4  1.000000  0.5  0.0  0.666667  0.000000
```

You can do the same with `(df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())`.

Comment: this works too : df.apply(lambda x: scaler.fit_transform(x))